# rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12)

Tags: shell, unix, ssh, rsync, scp

I'm trying to do an rsync to transfer 500GB of files from one server to another. I use this command;

> rsync -vrPt -e 'ssh -p 2222' uname@server.com:/folder /newfolder

It works and syncs just fine for about 10/15 minutes, then it throws this error every time;

> rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (5321016884 bytes received so
>   far) [receiver]  rsync: writefd_unbuffered failed to write 4 bytes to
>   socket [generator]: Broken pipe (32)  rsync error: error in rsync
>   protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(1525) [generator=3.0.6]  rsync
>   error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(600) [receiver=3.0.6]

What could the problem be?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it is a router timing out the NAT table entry.  (I assume one of the servers is on a DSL link.)

Or it could be this: "An idle connection caused a router or remote-shell server to close the connection." from http://rsync.samba.org/issues.html